How do I check if the result of symTake is equal to a concrete list?
This is my code:
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Grisette

x :: SymInteger
x = "x"

y :: SymInteger
y = "y"

numbers :: [SymInteger]
numbers = [x, y]

n :: SymInteger
n = "n"

result :: UnionM [SymInteger]
result = symTake n numbers

main :: IO ()
main = do
    print $ result .== [1, 2]

I want to check whether result can be equal to [1, 2]. I can test if a simple list of symbolic integers can be equal to [1, 2]. For example, I can do this:
x :: SymInteger
x = "x"

y :: SymInteger
y = "y"

main :: IO ()
main = do
    print $ [x, y] .== [1, 2]

But I can't find a way to do that with the result of symTake. Reading the code/docs in the code, it seems I'm not supposed to unbox the [SymInteger] out of the UnionM, but then I don't know how do check for equality.

I think you want:
print $ result .== mrgSingle [1, 2]

The issue here is that symTake applied to the list [x,y] can result in a list of size 0, 1, or 2, and unlike the fixed-length list numbers = [x,y], this requires a UnionM to be properly represented.  To compare a UnionM to a non-UnionM, you must use mrgSingle to promote the non-union.
The result looks plausible, if a little overcomplicated:
> main
(&& (! (<= 0 (- n))) (&& (! (<= -1 (- n))) (&& (= x 1) (= y 2))))


Thanks, it makes sense! And I can similarly issue a query: Right model <- solve (precise z3) $ result .== mrgSingle [1, 2] for anyone interested.

Thanks for the answer by K.A.Buhr. Since I don't regularly contribute to stack overflow, I lack the necessary reputation points to post this information as a comment.
Since Grisette v0.5.0.0, the function symTake has been renamed to mrgTake. This change was made to establish a more consistent naming convention within the library:

Functions prefixed with sym* can return non-union wrapped results.
Functions prefixed with mrg* usually return union-wrapped results.

This should make it a little clearer that you need to wrap the results in a UnionM in this scenario.
